# NSString quotedStringRepresentation crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, nsstring

In the production build, i am getting this type of crash log, but I am not able to understand it correctly as it points to the Foundation framework

Backtrace:

```
    OS Version: 10.2.1 (14D27)
    Device: iPhone 7 Plus
    RAM Free: 5.1%
    Disk Free: 54.7%

    #0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18cc6b014 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd33450 pthread_kill + 112
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18cbdf400 abort + 140
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18ccafa5c _nano_vet_and_size_of_live + 330
4  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18ccb0f18 nano_realloc + 376
5  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18cca3240 malloc_zone_realloc + 180
6  Foundation                     0x18e6ee628 -[NSString quotedStringRepresentation] + 732
7  Foundation                     0x18e6ce44c -[NSString _stringRepresentation] + 376
8  CoreFoundation                 0x18dbc4eec -[NSDictionary descriptionWithLocale:indent:] + 996
9  CoreFoundation                 0x18dbc84d4 _DescriptionWithLocaleFunc + 76
10 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc5e23c __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 7996
11 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc659b0 _CFStringAppendFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 36
12 CoreFoundation                 0x18dbc842c -[__NSCFString appendFormat:] + 308
13 Foundation                     0x18e78733c -[NSNotification description] + 256
14 Foundation                     0x18e790bec _NS_os_log_callback + 140
15 libsystem_trace.dylib          0x18cd57954 <redacted> + 112
16 libsystem_trace.dylib          0x18cd57564 <redacted> + 736
17 libsystem_trace.dylib          0x18cd56004 _os_log_impl + 792
18 MediaPlayer                    0x19871bc50 <redacted> + 228
19 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc36b10 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
20 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc36214 _CFXRegistrationPost + 400
21 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc35f90 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 60
22 CoreFoundation                 0x18dca5b8c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1504
23 CoreFoundation                 0x18db77e64 _CFXNotificationPost + 376
24 Foundation                     0x18e6ace0c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
25 Celestial                      0x1951115e4 <redacted> + 108
26 Celestial                      0x195111540 <redacted> + 372
27 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc36b10 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
28 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc36214 _CFXRegistrationPost + 400
29 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc35f90 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 60
30 CoreFoundation                 0x18dca5b8c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1504
31 CoreFoundation                 0x18db77e64 _CFXNotificationPost + 376
32 CoreFoundation                 0x18db9aca0 CFNotificationCenterPostNotification + 120
33 CoreMedia                      0x1905ca8c4 CMNotificationCenterPostNotification + 124
34 CoreMedia                      0x1905cab0c fncCallOriginalCallbackAndReleaseWeakListener + 80
35 CoreMedia                      0x1905ca5cc fncHandleWeakNotification + 204
36 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc36b10 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
37 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc36214 _CFXRegistrationPost + 400
38 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc35f90 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 60
39 CoreFoundation                 0x18dca5b8c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1504
40 CoreFoundation                 0x18db77e64 _CFXNotificationPost + 376
41 CoreFoundation                 0x18db9aca0 CFNotificationCenterPostNotification + 120
42 CoreMedia                      0x1905ca8c4 CMNotificationCenterPostNotification + 124
43 MediaToolbox                   0x194b7b5d0 <redacted> + 616
44 MediaToolbox                   0x194c9ab88 <redacted> + 1248
45 MediaToolbox                   0x194b7ad08 <redacted> + 132
46 MediaToolbox                   0x194b7ac58 <redacted> + 56
47 MediaToolbox                   0x194b76a60 <redacted> + 104
48 MediaToolbox                   0x194c9a4cc <redacted> + 16
49 libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb2b9f0 dispatch_mig_server + 576
50 libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb261bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
51 libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb32f94 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 576
52 libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb3f634 _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 204
53 libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb28160 _dispatch_source_invoke + 820
54 libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb2abbc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 572
55 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc4a810 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
56 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc483fc __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
57 CoreFoundation                 0x18db762b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
58 GraphicsServices               0x18f62a198 GSEventRunModal + 180
59 UIKit                          0x193bbd7fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
60 UIKit                          0x193bb8534 UIApplicationMain + 208
61 appname                        0x1000a7470 main (main.m:16)
62 libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb595b8 (Missing)

--

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18cc6b014 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd33450 pthread_kill + 112
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18cbdf400 abort + 140
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18ccafa5c _nano_vet_and_size_of_live + 330
4  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18ccb0f18 nano_realloc + 376
5  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18cca3240 malloc_zone_realloc + 180
6  Foundation                     0x18e6ee628 -[NSString quotedStringRepresentation] + 732
7  Foundation                     0x18e6ce44c -[NSString _stringRepresentation] + 376
8  CoreFoundation                 0x18dbc4eec -[NSDictionary descriptionWithLocale:indent:] + 996
9  CoreFoundation                 0x18dbc84d4 _DescriptionWithLocaleFunc + 76
10 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc5e23c __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 7996
11 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc659b0 _CFStringAppendFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 36
12 CoreFoundation                 0x18dbc842c -[__NSCFString appendFormat:] + 308
13 Foundation                     0x18e78733c -[NSNotification description] + 256
14 Foundation                     0x18e790bec _NS_os_log_callback + 140
15 libsystem_trace.dylib          0x18cd57954 <redacted> + 112
16 libsystem_trace.dylib          0x18cd57564 <redacted> + 736
17 libsystem_trace.dylib          0x18cd56004 _os_log_impl + 792
18 MediaPlayer                    0x19871bc50 <redacted> + 228
19 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc36b10 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
20 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc36214 _CFXRegistrationPost + 400
21 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc35f90 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 60
22 CoreFoundation                 0x18dca5b8c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1504
23 CoreFoundation                 0x18db77e64 _CFXNotificationPost + 376
24 Foundation                     0x18e6ace0c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
25 Celestial                      0x1951115e4 <redacted> + 108
26 Celestial                      0x195111540 <redacted> + 372
27 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc36b10 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
28 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc36214 _CFXRegistrationPost + 400
29 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc35f90 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 60
30 CoreFoundation                 0x18dca5b8c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1504
31 CoreFoundation                 0x18db77e64 _CFXNotificationPost + 376
32 CoreFoundation                 0x18db9aca0 CFNotificationCenterPostNotification + 120
33 CoreMedia                      0x1905ca8c4 CMNotificationCenterPostNotification + 124
34 CoreMedia                      0x1905cab0c fncCallOriginalCallbackAndReleaseWeakListener + 80
35 CoreMedia                      0x1905ca5cc fncHandleWeakNotification + 204
36 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc36b10 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
37 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc36214 _CFXRegistrationPost + 400
38 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc35f90 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 60
39 CoreFoundation                 0x18dca5b8c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1504
40 CoreFoundation                 0x18db77e64 _CFXNotificationPost + 376
41 CoreFoundation                 0x18db9aca0 CFNotificationCenterPostNotification + 120
42 CoreMedia                      0x1905ca8c4 CMNotificationCenterPostNotification + 124
43 MediaToolbox                   0x194b7b5d0 <redacted> + 616
44 MediaToolbox                   0x194c9ab88 <redacted> + 1248
45 MediaToolbox                   0x194b7ad08 <redacted> + 132
46 MediaToolbox                   0x194b7ac58 <redacted> + 56
47 MediaToolbox                   0x194b76a60 <redacted> + 104
48 MediaToolbox                   0x194c9a4cc <redacted> + 16
49 libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb2b9f0 dispatch_mig_server + 576
50 libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb261bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
51 libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb32f94 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 576
52 libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb3f634 _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 204
53 libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb28160 _dispatch_source_invoke + 820
54 libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb2abbc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 572
55 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc4a810 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
56 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc483fc __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
57 CoreFoundation                 0x18db762b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
58 GraphicsServices               0x18f62a198 GSEventRunModal + 180
59 UIKit                          0x193bbd7fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
60 UIKit                          0x193bb8534 UIApplicationMain + 208
61 appname                        0x1000a7470 main (main.m:16)
62 libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb595b8 (Missing)

#1. com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18cc4d188 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18cc4cff8 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18dc4a5d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18dc481ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18db762b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5  Foundation                     0x18e6b326c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x18e6d3dd0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7  UIKit                          0x194531c38 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8  Foundation                     0x18e7b0e68 __NSThread__start__ + 1024
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31850 <redacted> + 240
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31760 _pthread_start + 282
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ed94 thread_start + 4

#2. AVAudioSession Notify Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18cc4d188 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18cc4cff8 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18dc4a5d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18dc481ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18db762b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5  AVFAudio                       0x1a767bd24 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164
6  AVFAudio                       0x1a76a1d9c CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 84
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31850 <redacted> + 240
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31760 _pthread_start + 282
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ed94 thread_start + 4

#3. com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18cc4d188 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18cc4cff8 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18dc4a5d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18dc481ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18db762b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5  AudioToolbox                   0x190c440cc GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164
6  AudioToolbox                   0x190e1c230 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 84
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31850 <redacted> + 240
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31760 _pthread_start + 282
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ed94 thread_start + 4

#4. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18cc4d188 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18cc4cff8 mach_msg + 72
2  appname                        0x1002dc570 CLSMachExceptionServer + 4297590128
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31850 <redacted> + 240
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31760 _pthread_start + 282
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ed94 thread_start + 4

#5. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18cb7d5d4 strlen + 52
1  libc++.1.dylib                 0x18c69137c std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const + 28
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0x18c69137c std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const + 28
3  CFNetwork                      0x18e2bceec <redacted> + 236
4  CFNetwork                      0x18e48eb6c <redacted> + 76
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb261bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb337f0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 84
7  CFNetwork                      0x18e48eaf8 <redacted> + 96
8  CFNetwork                      0x18e2b36a4 <redacted> + 228
9  CFNetwork                      0x18e2b3858 <redacted> + 152
10 CFNetwork                      0x18e4085e0 <redacted> + 40
11 CFNetwork                      0x18e3d1c80 <redacted> + 136
12 CFNetwork                      0x18e3d2388 <redacted> + 248
13 CFNetwork                      0x18e425794 <redacted> + 88
14 CFNetwork                      0x18e423328 <redacted> + 32
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb261bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb31ab0 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 376
17 CFNetwork                      0x18e4d6598 <redacted> + 36
18 CoreFoundation                 0x18db75c18 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
19 CFNetwork                      0x18e4d647c <redacted> + 136
20 CFNetwork                      0x18e4d77a4 <redacted> + 312
21 CFNetwork                      0x18e4d7510 <redacted> + 64
22 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc4ab5c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
23 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc4a4a4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
24 CoreFoundation                 0x18dc480a4 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
25 CoreFoundation                 0x18db762b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
26 CFNetwork                      0x18e37ba70 <redacted> + 336
27 Foundation                     0x18e7b0e68 __NSThread__start__ + 1024
28 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31850 <redacted> + 240
29 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31760 _pthread_start + 282
30 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ed94 thread_start + 4

#6. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18cc6ae1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd309c0 <redacted> + 640
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0x18c6593ec std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 56
3  JavaScriptCore                 0x19247a5d0 <redacted> + 112
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x19247a544 <redacted> + 168
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x19247a424 <redacted> + 10
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x19247a6d4 <redacted> + 92
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31850 <redacted> + 240
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31760 _pthread_start + 282
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ed94 thread_start + 4

#7. WebThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18cc4d188 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18cc4cff8 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18dc4a5d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18dc481ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18db762b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5  WebCore                        0x19277c490 <redacted> + 456
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31850 <redacted> + 240
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31760 _pthread_start + 282
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ed94 thread_start + 4

#8. JIT Worklist Worker Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18cc6ae1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd309c0 <redacted> + 640
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0x18c6593ec std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 56
3  JavaScriptCore                 0x192462d64 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 2132
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x19223aa5c <redacted> + 192
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x19223aeac <redacted> + 14
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x191bab00c <redacted> + 212
7  JavaScriptCore                 0x191baaf1c <redacted> + 24
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31850 <redacted> + 240
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31760 _pthread_start + 282
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ed94 thread_start + 4

#9. WTF Parallel Helper Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18cc6ae1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd309c0 <redacted> + 640
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0x18c6593ec std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 56
3  JavaScriptCore                 0x192462d64 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 2132
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x1924622e8 <redacted> + 288
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x192462088 <redacted> + 76
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x191bab00c <redacted> + 212
7  JavaScriptCore                 0x191baaf1c <redacted> + 24
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31850 <redacted> + 240
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd31760 _pthread_start + 282
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ed94 thread_start + 4

#10. Thread
0  CoreFoundation                 0x18dc3c680 __CFTSDFinalize + 40
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ffbc <redacted> + 572
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2fce4 <redacted> + 200
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2f378 _pthread_wqthread + 1502
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ed8c start_wqthread + 4

#11. Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ed88 pthread_workqueue_addthreads_np + 126

#12. Thread
0  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18cca1a04 szone_size + 192
1  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18cca171c free + 108
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb2eb1c _dispatch_cache_cleanup + 24
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ffbc <redacted> + 572
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2fce4 <redacted> + 200
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2f378 _pthread_wqthread + 1502
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ed8c start_wqthread + 4

#13. Thread
0  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18ccafbb4 _nano_vet_and_size_of_live + 344
1  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18cca171c free + 108
2  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18cca171c free + 108
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x18cb2eb1c _dispatch_cache_cleanup + 24
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ffbc <redacted> + 572
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2fce4 <redacted> + 200
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2f378 _pthread_wqthread + 1502
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ed8c start_wqthread + 4

#14. Thread
0  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18ccafbb4 _nano_vet_and_size_of_live + 344
1  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18cca171c free + 108
2  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x18cca171c free + 108
3  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18cb7d490 gdtoa_freelist_free + 48
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ffbc <redacted> + 572
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2fce4 <redacted> + 200
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2f378 _pthread_wqthread + 1502
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ed8c start_wqthread + 4

#15. Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ed88 pthread_workqueue_addthreads_np + 126

#16. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18cc6ba88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2f160 _pthread_wqthread + 968
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ed8c start_wqthread + 4

#17. Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18cd2ed88 pthread_workqueue_addthreads_np + 126
```

Based on trace I am assuming it may crash because of Bad value in the dictionary key.

How can i get more information and what can be solution for this?

Comment: try with adding Exception Breakpoint, this will help to get the location of crashing in your case.

Comment: @Mady : Problem is it is coming in production build, I am not able to replicate this development environment

Comment: Can you share whole crash log at least for last thread. where the application get crashed.

Comment: @Mady updated the backtrace, is this you want?

Comment: Its look like you want to update the string which you are getting from the Notification. Can you update the string in main thread using dispatch